# How to add capping into my jQuery FB like plugin?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I have a jQuery plugin, which appears the box with Facebook Like button in the nottom-right corner of my page, when someone scrolls the page - that's code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var counter = 0;
    $(window).ready(function(){

$(window).click(function () { 
    $('#likebox').animate({right: 10, bottom: 10});
    $.cookie("value", counter , {path: "/", expires: 30});  
    counter++;
});

$('#likebox .close').click(function(){
    alert($.cookie("value"));
    $('#likebox').css('visibility', 'hidden');

});
```

});

It works perfectly when I'm on my page, scrolling it - the box appears, but my problem is that the box always appears to me and my users every time they're going to another page etc. How can I limit it to 3 times (for example) for one unique IP daily?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would probably have to use some server side code to do this, or you could use Javascript cookies that expire in 24 hrs

http://www.electrictoolbox.com/jquery-cookies/

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).ready(function(){
        if($.cookie("example")<=3){
            $(window).scroll(function () { 
                $('#likebox').animate({right: 10, bottom: 10});
            });

            $('#likebox .close').click(function(){
                $('#likebox').css('visibility', 'hidden');
            });
        }else{
            if($.cookie("example")!="undefined"){
                var newVal = $.cookie("example")+1;
                $.cookie("example", newVal);
            }else{
                $.cookie("example", 1);
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Cookies seems interesting - i'll take a look : ) Thanks!

Comment: You could increment the value stored in the cookie, the only run the code if the cookie is less than say 3

Comment: When i'll set the name of cookie to 'counter' and i will increment it whenever the script is loaded => will it affect only one user or all of them? I mean, cookies are individual for everyone? I don't want one user to use my script 3 times, and for the rest of the day noone will see it :D

Comment: Cookies only affect single computers, in other words, it will only show 3 times to each individual person

Comment: Bloafer, could you suggest me where should i set my counter? Cause when i'm setting it in my script - it's refreshing to 0 every time I enter the page (it's obvious : )) but i have no idea, where can i put it. (i update my code to the recent version in the 1st post.

Comment: Thanks : ) but i see you have mistaken the logic in some way ; ) - if cookie<=3 you don't adding up the values, am i right

Comment: Yes just need to remove the first else statement :)

Answer (score 0):

You can add a server side check for that. And display portion of the code only when the validation satisfies.